# ClassCastException for passing Context to Interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, classcastexception

I am trying to pass Context from the Fragment to the RecyclerView Adapter which contains an interface.
I created an interface in my Adapter to communicate between the Fragment which requires Context.
When I run the Fragment the App Crashes with the Error:-
**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.naztec.storesy.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.naztec.storesy.Adapters.CartItemsAdapter$updatePrices**

Code is given below :-
**CartFragment.java**

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment implements CartItemsAdapter.updatePrices {

    RecyclerView rvCartItems;
    List<CartItemsModel> cartItemsList;
    TextView cartTotalPrice;

    public CartFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);

        rvCartItems = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_cart_items);
        rvCartItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));

        cartItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        cartItemsList.add(new CartItemsModel("Product 1", "4999", "3999"));
        cartItemsList.add(new CartItemsModel("Product 2", "4999", "3999"));
        cartItemsList.add(new CartItemsModel("Product 3", "4999", "3999"));
        cartItemsList.add(new CartItemsModel("Product 4", "4999", "3999"));
        cartItemsList.add(new CartItemsModel("Product 5", "4999", "3999"));


        CartItemsAdapter adapter = new CartItemsAdapter(cartItemsList, getContext());
        rvCartItems.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        cartTotalPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.cart_price_details_total_price);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPriceUpdate(String price) {
        // For Instance
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**CartItemsAdapter.java**

```
public class CartItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemsAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    List<CartItemsModel> cartItemsList;
    List<String> prodTotalPrices;
    updatePrices context;

    public CartItemsAdapter(List<CartItemsModel> cartItemsList, Context context) {
        this.cartItemsList = cartItemsList;
        prodTotalPrices = new ArrayList<>();
        this.context = (updatePrices) context;
    }

    public interface updatePrices {
        void onPriceUpdate(String priceList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_cart_items, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Some Code Here
        context.onPriceUpdate(cartItemsList.get(position).getPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartItemsList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView prodName, prodMrp, prodPrice;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // Some Code here
        }

       
    }

}
```

NOTE:- **MainActivity is Navigation Drawer Activity and CartFragment is opening in the MainActivity**

Comment: Change the 2nd parameter of `CartItemsAdapter` to a `updatePrices` type (which the fragment can still be used) or add a third parameter if you still need a `Context` object (which the code posted does not).  Just use `this` as the 2nd actual parameter in the fragment where the adapter is `new`ed.  Since the `context` variable is only used for its interface contract it should suffice.  However, the naming used is confusing since it's not a `Context` object which is a common term in Activities and such.

Comment: Thanks Andy It worked.But I am unable to understand why this problem occurs, previously when I use the same code in my other project on an Activity it worked but the Activity wasn't the Navigation Drawer Activity. What could be the problem?